# Menu icon does not open menu after clicking a link

Tags: css, responsive-design, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, turbolinks

I am developing an app using Rails 4 and Foundation 4. I'm using the top-bar navigation elements from Foundation 4 which hide the menu in a menu icon when the display is small.

The problem I am having is that I can only toggle the menu when the page is first loaded (after going to it directly or reloading it). If I click on any links, the menu stops working until the page is refreshed.

If I open up Chome's debugger I find

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
```

Googling that seemed to show it was a bug in Chrome, but Firefox doesn't work, nor does my phone.

Here is my code for the top bar

```
<nav class="top-bar">
<ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
        <h1><%= link_to "My App",root_path %></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>
<section class="top-bar-section">
<!-- Right Nav Section -->
<ul class="right">
  <% if signed_in? %>
    <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
    <li><%= link_to "My Account", account_path %></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
  <% end %>

  <li class="divider show-for-small"></li>
  <li class="has-form">
    <% if signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path, class: "button", method: "delete" %>
    <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Sign In", signin_path, class: "button" %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
</section>
</nav>
```

Any ideas on how to get this working? I haven't changed any of the css for the top-bar and I'm using Foundation 4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is caused by TurboLinks in Rails 4.0

I found this page http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2013/06/28/troubleshooting-turbolinks-with-rails-4/ that talks about a solution.

My application.js file looks like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation

$(document).foundation();
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

and I had to add the following line to my Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```